# Keyboard Issues with Ionic4

Tags: typescript, ionic3, angular5, ionic4

I have developed an android application using Ionic4. The issue I am facing is when the keyboard appears it covers the Input field, screen is not moving up.
I have solved this issue in Ionic 3 by the following lines of code. But this does not works in Ionic4. Somebody please help.

```
imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {
    scrollAssist: true,
    autoFocusAssist: true
    })
  ],
```

### HTML

```
<div class="field-container">
    <form [formGroup]="credentialsForm" class="width-100">
        <ion-list>
            <ion-item no-padding class="transparent-border">
                <div class="logo-div">
                    <img src="assets/icon/favicon.png" class="app-logo">
                </div>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item no-padding>
                <ion-label position="floating" color="primary">Username</ion-label>
                <ion-input type="text" color="primary" mode="ios" maxLength="5" formControlName="userName" required></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
            <span class="validation-errors" *ngIf="!credentialsForm.controls.userName.valid && (credentialsForm.controls.userName.dirty || onSaveAttempt)">Username
                is mandatory</span>
            <ion-item no-padding>
                <ion-label position="floating" color="primary">Password</ion-label>
                <ion-input color="primary" type="password" mode="ios" formControlName="password" required></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
            <span class="validation-errors" *ngIf="!credentialsForm.controls.password.valid && (credentialsForm.controls.password.dirty || onSaveAttempt)">Password
                is mandatory</span>
            <ion-item no-padding class="transparent-border">
                <div style="overflow: hidden;width: 100%">
                    <p class="create-account" (click)="doRegistrationNavigation()">Create an Account</p>
                    <p class="forgot-password">Forgot password?</p>
                </div>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </form>
    <ion-button (click)="doLogin()" expand="block" shape="round" class="signin-button" color="vibrant">Sign
        In</ion-button>
</div>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
window.addEventListener('keyboardDidShow', this.customScroll);
}

private customScroll() {
 this.content.scrollTo(0, 100); // 100 replaced by your value
}
```

Comment: I have some 15+ pages in my application. Doing this in each one, is it a good practice?

Comment: Done this in your root page.

Comment: what should be content?

Comment: It should be comes under the routerOutlet so its not an issue. just try this.

Comment: Hi! Having the same issue, but this workaround didn't work. How should it be done?